# Why is my SSD Journal drive's WriteCacheSize blank in Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I'm trying to setup storage spaces to use what I believe is called "write back cache". I originally had 1 SSD and 6 HDDs, I found it painfully slow.  So I replaced one HDD with an SSD, and I added one more SSD.

I'm trying to use the two Journal SSDs in the below list as the write back cache.  I'm assuming I should see a value in the second image, but as you can see, it's blank.

Any advice?

[image]

[image]

They're all part of one pool.
[image]